# Display table in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKT6s.png)

I have a table that I used to display on page load but now I need to display on click of a button 'Request Questions'.

```
[<tr id="displayQuestions">
        <td>
            <div style="width: 100%; ">
            <fieldset class="panelBorder">
                <legend class="panelTitle">Identity Information</legend>
                <form:label class="panelLabel" path="" style="width: 30%;">Credit History Questions</form:label>
                <form:input id="formChallengeResponse" class="panelValueDisabled" path="challengeResponse" style="width: 70%;" readonly="true"/>
                <form:label class="panelLabel" path="" style="width: 30%;">One-time Passcode</form:label>
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="button" id="creditQuestions" style="float: left;" name="creditQuestions" value="Request Credit History Questions"></input>
                <br>
                <form:input id="formOTPResponse" class="panelValueDisabled" path="otp" readonly="true"/>
                <div id="formTuAuthFailed" class="sectionErrorFull" style="color: #666666; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Insufficient data available for credit history questions. <br> Please validate borrower's identity using an alternative method.<br><br><br><br></div>
                <div id="challengeQuestionsReponseFailed" class="sectionErrorFull" style="color: #666666; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Please validate borrower's identity using an alternative method.<br><br><br><br><br></div>
                <div id="formSecurityQuestSection" class="security-question">
                    <%int index = 0;%>
                    <c:forEach items="${securityVO.questions.challengeQuestions}" var="quest">
                        <div class="squestion"><c:out value="${quest.question}"></c:out></div>
                        <%String questPath = "answers.challengeAnswers\[" + index + "\].questionName";%>
                        <form:input class="panelValue, hidden-form-field" path="<%=questPath%>" value="${quest.questionName}"/>
                        <c:forEach  items="${quest.answers}" var="ans">
                            <%String indexName = "qOption" + index;%>
                            <%String idName = "formQOption" + index;%>
                            <%String ansPath = "answers.challengeAnswers\[" + index + "\].answerKey";%>
                            <div class="sanswer"><form:radiobutton name="<%=indexName%>" id="<%=idName%>" path="<%=ansPath%>" value="${ans.answerKey}" label="${ans.answer}"/></div><br/>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <%index = index + 1; %>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
                <form:input id="formNoQuestion" class="panelValue, hidden-form-field" path="isNoQuestion" />
                <form:input id="challengeQuestionFailure" class="panelValue, hidden-form-field" path="responseFailure" />
            </fieldset>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>][1]

$("[id='creditQuestions']").on("click", function(e)
    {
    alert("testing security==");
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/security/creditQuestions",

            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("testing security after succes==");
                alert("json name==="+response.questions.challengeQuestions[0].questionName);
                alert("json ==="+response.questions.challengeQuestions[0].question);


                 $.each(response, function(value, key) {                 
                     alert("response"+ response);
                  //how do i include my table code (attached above) here

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                return; 
            },
            error: function (response) {
                return;
            }
        });
});
```

I put an alert to make sure I am getting questions and answers in the ajax response. I should now display both questions and answers in the table on button click like its happening on page load. This has to be done in Ajax call after success response. I am new to Ajax, can anyone help me on this? How can I loop my repsonse and display in a format attached.

Comment: What is that embedded in your table, java? Doesn't look compatible to me.

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: You are not getting an answer because your question is confusing. Looks like you are mixing two different languages. Be more specific about what you need to do.

Comment: This is all in one JSP, the whole tr code that you see, currently we are already using that to display the table but this happens on page load, now I need to stop displaying the table on page load. I need to display the table on click of this new button that I have created. In the ajax call, I cannot just take the div id and formSecurityQuestSection.show(), this doesnt work, I need to embed the code, take the response from the service and display in a table after ajax success call.

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying. Your template is JSP and you are trying to generate it inside an AJAX call, won't work. You need to convert it to a javascript function instead. Are you trying to fill the template with response data?

Comment: yes you're right!